# How do I access git environment data within a jenkins plugin using pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to get the git commit hash of the current build from within a plugin (that is, in a Java class that extends hudson.tasks.Recorder).

This works for a freestyle project:

```
EnvVars env = run.getEnvironment(listener);
String hash = env.get("GIT_COMMIT");
```

However, in pipeline projects, the GIT_COMMIT environment variable is evidently not set, so hash becomes null. This is true even for a declarative pipeline where the scm checkout step is implicit.

Is there an alternative way to get the commit hash in a pipeline project?

Edit: To clarify, this is regarding getting git commit hash from the Java code in a Jenkins plugin, not in groovy/Jenkinsfile. It seems like the environment variable will not exist when the plugin is used in pipeline jobs, so I'm looking for a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue - here's how I solved it. The trick is to do it inside you `StepExecution` class, as it has access to the `StepContext` - you can then get the set of environment variables from there.  The code is like this:

```
public class MyExecution extends SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution<ReturnType> {
    ...

    @Override
    protected ReturnType run() throws Exception {
        try {
            StepContext context = getContex();
            EnvVars env = context.get(EnvVars.class);
            ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Sounds like this could work - but the more common (I think) way of creating a plugin with pipeline support is to use a BuildStep which implements SimpleBuildStep, and not use the workflow plugin at all. Your method only works if you go the workflow-plugin way.

Comment: By the way, did you try to acces SCM-specific environment variables this way?

Comment: @Gutskalk I have steps extending from `org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.Step`. The step then requires an execution, which in my case extends from `SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution`.  Inside this execution I can use the code I showed.  I haven't tried getting scm info myself.  I suspect, you could get `Run` from there, then use `getParent` on it to access the job itself - and from the job you should be able to get SCM details.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `currentBuild` variable. It holds a `changeSets` field which has the details about the list of commits.

From the doc:

> changeSets
>
> a list of changesets coming from distinct SCM checkouts; each has a
>   kind and is a list of commits; each commit has a commitId, timestamp,
>   msg, author, and affectedFiles each of which has an editType and path;

Comment: I do not have access to any "currentBuild" variable. I need to do this from the "perform" method of a SimpleBuildStep - only this way will the plugin work with pipeline jobs. In this perform method I have access to a run  (hudson.model.Run), but not a build (hudson.model.Build). I see that builds (but not runs) do have a getChangeSet() method, but even from there I can't see how to get the commit hash.